# Writing an API to POST to a many-to-many relationship

Tags: c#, asp.net, api, entity-framework, many-to-many

Good evening all

This is probably an easy question for experienced developers, but I am new to C#, ASP.Net and Entity Framework.  I have two tables - AppUser and CompanySettings.  There is a many-to-many relationship between these 2 tables.

```
    public class AppUser
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string UserName { get; set; }
        public byte[] PasswordHash { get; set; }
        public byte[] PasswordSalt { get; set; }
        public string KnownAs { get; set; }
        public DateTime Created { get; set; } = DateTime.Now;
        public DateTime LastActive {get; set;} = DateTime.Now;
        public ICollection<Photo> Photos { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<AppUserCompanySettings> AppUserCompanySettings { get; set; }
    }
```

```
public class CompanySettings
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string CompanyName { get; set; }
        public string CompanyRegistrationNumber { get; set; }
        public bool isActive { get; set; }
        public bool isArchived { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<AppUserCompanySettings> AppUserCompanySettings { get; set; }

    }
```

I also created the join table:

```
public class AppUserCompanySettings
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public int AppUserId { get; set; }
        public virtual AppUser AppUser { get; set; }
        public int CompanySettingsId { get; set; }
        public virtual CompanySettings CompanySettings { get; set; }
    }
```

My API now looks like this:

```
public async Task<ActionResult<CompanySettings>> AddNewCompany(CompanySettings companySettings)
        {
            if (await CompanyExists(companySettings.CompanyRegistrationNumber)) return
                BadRequest("Company already exists.  Please contact our Support team for assistance");

            var user = new AppUser {
                Id = 1
            };

            var company = new CompanySettings
            {
                CompanyName = companySettings.CompanyName,
                CompanyRegistrationNumber = companySettings.CompanyRegistrationNumber,
                isActive = companySettings.isActive,
                isArchived = companySettings.isArchived,
            };

            _context.CompanySettings.Add(company);
            _context.Update(user);
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

            return company;
        }
```

A user registers - and this writes username and password to the AppUser table.  He does not need to create a company on registration.

However, when he wants to add a Company (that writes to Company Settings), how do I write an API to post to the CompanySettings table as well as the AppuserCompanySettings table that EF created?

At the moment, if I call the API, it creates the company.  But it does not do the join to the AppUserCompanySettings.

How do I update the Join table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ensure you heve this in your `DbContext` configuration:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

    modelBuilder.Entity<AppUser>()
        .HasMany(x => x.AppUserCompanySettings )
        .WithOne(x => x.AppUser)
        .HasForeignKey(x => x.AppUserId);

    modelBuilder.Entity<CompanySettings>()
        .HasMany(x => x.AppUserCompanySettings)
        .WithOne(x => x.CompanySettings)
        .HasForeignKey(x => x.CompanySettingsId);

    modelBuilder.Entity<AppUserCompanySettings>()
        .HasKey(x => new {x.AppUserId, x.CompanySettingsId});

}
```

Replace `public int Id { get; set; }` from your `AppUserCompanySettings`, since you only have 2 foreign keys in your table, which act like a primary

After this piece of code:

```
var user = new AppUser 
{
    Id = 1
};

var company = new CompanySettings
{
    CompanyName = companySettings.CompanyName,
    CompanyRegistrationNumber = companySettings.CompanyRegistrationNumber,
    isActive = companySettings.isActive,
    isArchived = companySettings.isArchived,
};
```

You have to do this:

```
// adding relationship between entities here
user.AppUserCompanySettings.Add(new AppUserCompanySettings 
{
    AppUser = user, 
    CompanySettings = company
});

// if you haven't created a new user but used already existing - 
// replace Add with Update
_context.Add(user);
_context.SaveChanges();
```

Also modify your Collections in `AppUser` and `CompanySettings` like this

```
public virtual ICollection<AppUserCompanySettings> AppUserCompanySettings { get; set; } = new List<AppUserCompanySettings>();
```

Comment: Hi Timur.  Thank you so much for your feedback.  I tried the above but I get an internal server error.  I know that this is because I am not setting the UserId.  But I have no idea how to do this in a many-to-many relationship scenario, and the course I am doing does not help much with this either.  I have amended the original question with the code I am using for the API call.  Could you please assist?  Thank you

Comment: Can you provide the exact exception message, please?

Comment: Also, you can create your own representation of many-to-many relationship. You just have to create one more class, named just like your table `AppUserCompanySettings `. It will then have two properties: `UserId` and `CompanyId`. Then you would have `List<AppUserCompanySettings>` in both `AppUser` and `CompanySettings` classes (these will replace collections, which were previously user). You can then create a relationship object and add it to those collections

Comment: Hi Timur.  I have added the Exception Message to the original question.  I am also playing around with the second option of creating my own representation of the many-to-many relationship.

Comment: Well, it seems like a null ref. Have you initialized your collections? I Assume it breaks on line `user.CompanySettings.Add(company);`. Can you verify that it's not null?

Comment: Verify other props for null ref aswell, please

Comment: Hi Timur.  I have changed the code a bit.  I created my own representation for the many-to-many relationship.  I also attempted to update my API call.  It runs successful, but it does not write to my join table.  Again, thank you so much for helping me.

Comment: Good morning Timur.  Thank you so much for your help.  It worked!  I get an error 500 at the moment but that is because I am using the Entity itself, and not a DTO.  I will fix that soon.